# Sort array of weekdays with current day as 1st element in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array of weekdays with current day being the 1st element in the array.

Current day :

```
$day=date("l");
```

The $day gives me Thursday

Input:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Wednesday 9:30AM-6PM
  [1] => Thursday 9:30AM-9PM
  [2] => Friday 9:30AM-7PM
  [3] => Saturday 9AM-6PM
  [4] => Sunday 10AM-6PM
  [5] => Monday 9:30AM-6PM
  [6] => Tuesday 9:30AM-6PM
)
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Thursday 9:30AM-9PM
  [1] => Friday 9:30AM-7PM
  [2] => Saturday 9AM-6PM
  [3] => Sunday 10AM-6PM
  [4] => Monday 9:30AM-6PM
  [5] => Tuesday 9:30AM-6PM
  [6] => Wednesday 9:30AM-6PM
)
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5055418/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$day=date("l");

$data = Array
(
  '0' => 'Wednesday 9:30AM-6PM',
  '1' => 'Thursday 9:30AM-9PM',
  '2' => 'Friday 9:30AM-7PM',
  '3' => 'Saturday 9AM-6PM',
  '4' => 'Sunday 10AM-6PM',
  '5' => 'Monday 9:30AM-6PM',
  '6' => 'Tuesday 9:30AM-6PM'
);
$new_date_array = array();
$count = count($data);
foreach($data as $key=> $dat){
   if(strpos($dat, $day) !== false){ // get the key where input day matched
        for ($i =$key; $i<$count;$i++){ // add next all records to the new array till the end of the original array
            if(isset($data[$i])){
                $new_date_array[] = $data[$i];
            }

        }
        for ($j=0; $j<=$key-1;$j++){ // add previous one before the matched key to the new array
            if(isset($data[$j])){
                $new_date_array[] = $data[$j];
            }

        }
   }
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_date_array);
```

Output:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Thursday 9:30AM-9PM
    [1] => Friday 9:30AM-7PM
    [2] => Saturday 9AM-6PM
    [3] => Sunday 10AM-6PM
    [4] => Monday 9:30AM-6PM
    [5] => Tuesday 9:30AM-6PM
    [6] => Wednesday 9:30AM-6PM
)
```

One more output (when i changed day for comparison manually):-https://eval.in/633102

Comment: Thanks @anant , the above code doesn't add the previous key and how can i sort the weekdays ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do an extra array with your time.

```
$day=date("l");

$timeArray = array(
    "Monday" => "9:30AM-6PM",
    "Tuesday" => "9:30AM-6PM",
    "Wednesday" => "9:30AM-6PM",
    "Thursday" => "9:30AM-9PM",
    "Friday" => "9:30AM-7PM",
    "Saturday" => "9AM-6PM",
    "Sunday" => "10AM-6PM"
    );
```

then you could map this with your `$day`

```
$timestamp = strtotime($day);
$days = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $dayname = strftime('%A', $timestamp);
    $days[] = $dayname." ".$timeArray[$dayname];
    $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
}
```

Output:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "Thursday 9:30AM-9PM"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "Friday 9:30AM-7PM"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "Saturday 9AM-6PM"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "Sunday 10AM-6PM"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "Monday 9:30AM-6PM"
  [5]=>
  string(18) "Tuesday 9:30AM-6PM"
  [6]=>
  string(20) "Wednesday 9:30AM-6PM"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will shift the item at the start to the end. Is this what you are after? Your question was a little confusing. Hope this helps :)

```
$array = ["m", "t", "w", "t", "f", "s", "s"];

$array[6] = array_shift($array);
print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => t [1] => w [2] => t [3] => f [4] => s [5] => s [6] => m )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$day=date("w")`, which will set `$day` to 4 for thursday in your example. Create your base array in a way, that sunday is at index 0, monday at 1, ... and saturday at 6.

Now, you can copy the items into your output array by looping from `$day` to `$day + 6` and selecting the index `($day + $i) % 7` from you source array.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: reference [Rotating a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5055418/3933332)

```
$a = array('monday 123','tuesday 874','saturday 889', 'Thursday 123');
$b = array_filter($a, function($val){
if(strpos($val, date("l")) !== false) {
  return $val;
}
});

$i = key($b);
$arr2 = array_merge(array_slice($a, $i), array_slice($a, 0, $i));

print_r($arr2);
```

> Array ( [0] => Thursday 123 [1] => monday 123 [2] => tuesday 874 [3] => saturday 889 )

What I have done here is filtered the day which you want as first element and taken its numeric index as refrerence to regenerate the output.